# C++ Immutability through a type alias

Tags: c++, immutability, using-declaration

Is it wrong, okay or a good practice to use a `using` declaration to make an immutable version of a type ?

```
struct MutableA
{
  int i;
  float f;
};

using ImmutableA = const MutableA;
```

For pointer or ref members a wrapper like [propagate_const](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) would insure const safety in the Immutable object.

The benefit of this would be that there would be no cost to converting the Mutable to the Immutable type (I presume), and avoid code duplication.

Is it a good practice ? Is it wrong ? Is it useless ?

Comment: That's what `const` is for, right? You're just making an alias which is fine I guess? Although `const MutableA` is easier to read/understand imo.

Comment: IMO it is making the code harder to read. Also, I suggest you focus on whether there will be lurking bugs introduced by doing so instead of asking about its merits, which is opinion based.

Comment: `const` is how C++ programmers designate immutability. You provide syntactic sugar instead of idiomatic code.

Comment: I've just never seen this in any code, that's why I wonder. I'm looking to use it for a struct that should be almost always immutable and only mutable for the producer. That's why I'd rather have an alias, to avoid someone forgetting the const and make this struct immutable "by default"

Comment: @Michel You may also consider making those fields private and provide appropriate constructor and/or const getters.

Comment: @freakish How would the producer modify it, then ? Should I make it a class hierarchy with a modifiable derived class ? Is it a better practice ?

Comment: @Michel There are several possibilities, e.g.: (1) the producer is a friend class, (2) the producer creates some intermediate, internal, mutable class and before producing the final results it copies the content to the destination class (via appropriate constructor). This heavily depends on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent honest mistakes or malicious misuse? This approach won't prevent either.

Comment: I've read that some people advise making immutable classes. It is supposed to be easier to read/understand and less error prone. I'm just looking for a good way to do so ! I'm not very satisfied with the idea of making a different class which would duplicate a lot of code and require copy at runtime (as far as I understand it). The friend solution proposed by freakish sounds like a possible approach, though. I would probably have to make a producer base class that passes this friend access to its children (as protected methods), but it seems feasible.

Comment: @Michel you don't necessarily have a runtime hit, this can (and in many cases will) be optimized by the compiler (especially if the intermediate class is private to the producer). You would have to test it. Remember that immutability is for the developer only, the cpu doesn't care.  Also more code doesn't necessarily mean "harder to maintain". But again, the approach heavily depends on your actual case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, it's just trying to make things more expressive. Expressive code is Good(TM).

Most importantly, though, I'd note that `const` does not mean `immutable`.

Here's a sample:

```
using ImmutableString = std::string const;
std::string s = "Hello world";

ImmutableString& helloWorld = s;
s = "Bye!";

std::cout << helloWorld; // prints Bye!
```

Another angle is:

```
struct X {
     mutable int i;
};

using ImmutableX = X const;

ImmutableX x { 42 };
x.i = 666; // no problem
```

Finally, what about:

```
struct X {
     int i;
};

using ImmutableX = X const;

ImmutableX* p = new ImmutableX{42};

// now p->i = 666; is not OK, because it's const

delete p; // whoops, not so immutable after all?
```

Here might be more background info: [Difference between immutable and const](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149555/difference-between-immutable-and-const])

Comment: Thank you! It makes it plain clear that it is not a valid approach!